# Calling classes from files

Tags: ruby

I am writing a program which includes two file. I’m the first file all I am doing is initializing the next file which includes multiple classes. I call the class at the bottom of the file, but it runs the class at the top of the file.
Btw I am running ruby

First file:

```
Require ‘./secondfile.rb’

newfile.Lastclass
```

Second file:

```
class Firstclass

end

class Lastclass

end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hint #1.** It's better to write without `.`

It depends on directory from where you run your app.

For example you have directory *folder*. And there you have two files:

*file.rb*

```
puts "I'm file.rb"
```

*main.rb*

```
require './file.rb'
```

If you run your app from *folder* - it's ok:

```
folder$ ruby main.rb
I'm file.rb
```

But if you'll run it from high level - it will be error:

```
folder$ cd ..
:~$ ruby folder/main.rb 
kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./file.rb (LoadError)
```

But how to write in this case?

**Hint #2.** You can use [special method](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel:__dir__)

*main.rb*

```
require "./#{__dir__}/file.rb"
```

Now it's ok in all cases:

```
~$ ruby folder/main.rb 
I'm file.rb

folder$ ruby main.rb 
I'm file.rb
```

But you can write it better.

**Hint #3.** You can use `require_relative`

*main.rb*

```
require_relative 'file.rb'
```

And even better.

*main.rb*

```
require_relative 'file'
```

Ruby understand it.

```
~$ ruby folder/main.rb 
I'm file.rb

folder$ ruby main.rb 
I'm file.rb
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are injected into the root namespace if they're defined. If another file defines a class, *all* files get it:

```
require_relative './secondfile.rb'

Lastclass
```

This is unlike JavaScript (e.g. Node.js) where you must explicitly import classes from other files. In Ruby it happens by manipulating the root namespace.

Another note is to pay close attention to which slashes you use. In your code you used a backslash, which is incorrect. You also used the wrong quotes. Often *every character counts when programming*.

Comment: Adding require_relative still runs the first class even when I call the last class

Comment: What do you mean "runs the first class?" If both classes are defined in the file, both classes get defined when you `require` or `require_relative`. The only way to load just one definition is to split them into different files. This is how Ruby code is normally organized: One class per file, and one class only.